# Yii2: overloading CSS of extension

Tags: css, yii2, assets

I'm using the extension [dmstr/yii2-cookie-consent](https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-cookie-consent) for cookie consent and I want to modify the CSS of the extension. The CSS in the extension is included as AssetBundle.

Here are my questions:

- How to overload the extension's CSS with my CSS during deleopment (no AssetBundle, no cahing)?
- How to use my CSS in production, i.e. is it possible to permanently overwrite an extension's CSS (using caching of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development you can use

```php
$this->registerCss(".your-css {}")
```

for prototyping

When going live you can overload the extensions asset bundle using dependency injection

```php
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'dmstr\cookieconsent\assets\CookieConsentAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => '/path/to/your/source/path',
            'css' => [
                'css/yourstyles.css'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Keep in mind that the package offers the functionality to load assets depending on the app env. In production mode a compressed version of the css is loaded.

https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-cookie-consent/blob/master/src/assets/CookieConsentAsset.php#L20

Comment: When using depency injection, is my CSS going to be compressed, too?

Comment: Depends on your configuration. Have a look at this: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#combining-compressing-assets

Answer (score 1):

Adding just as another option

If I am not wrong you are using the widget I would extend the function [`run()`](https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-cookie-consent/blob/master/src/widgets/CookieConsent.php#L218) which is registering the scripts and create my own asset class file with my custom css file loaded.

I assume that you are using the advance-app for Yii2, or adjust the namespace accordingly.

The `AssetBundle` class

```
<?php

namespace common\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class CookieConsentAsset extends AssetBundle
{

    public $sourcePath = __DIR__;

    public $css = [
        'path/to/custom.css',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'dmstr\cookieconsent\assets\CookieConsentAsset'
    ];

}
```

and extend the widget class under `common\components` or `common\widgets` or whatever suits you

```
<?php
namespace common\components;

use dmstr\cookieconsent\widgets\CookieConsent as BaseCookieConsent;
use common\assets\CookieConsentAsset;

class CookieConsent extends BaseCookieConsent
{
    public function run(){
        CookieConsentAsset::register($this->view);
        parent::run();
    }
}
```

Now you can use your own widget by changing the namespace to

```
<?php
    use common\components\CookieConsent;

    echo CookieConsent::widget();
```